# Django HTML issue with HTML text formatting

Tags: html, django

I am developing django site locally, I have some issues with Formatting of text (highlighted yellow).
On a main blog yellow is incorrectly showing that HTMl tags, although when I enter detailed view of post I see all is ok.

Do you know what can be issue?

incorrect:
[image: formating]

correct:
[image: correct]

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Django Central</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine"> 
        <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
            crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
            body {
            font-family: "Tangerine", serif;
            font-size: 37;
            background-color: #fdfdfd;
        }
        .shadow {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        .btn-danger {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #f00000;
            border-color: #dc281e;
        }
        .masthead {
            background: #3398E1;
            height: auto;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
        img {
            width: 00%;
            height: auto;
            object-fit: contain; 
    </style>
        {% load static %}
               <center> <img src="{% static 'blog/moj.png' %}" alt="My image"> </center>

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light shadow" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                
                
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="/">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="portfolio/">Moje projekty/ Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="#">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        {% block content %}
        <!-- Content Goes here -->
        {% endblock content %}
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="py-3 bg-grey">
            <p class="m-0 text-dark text-center ">Copyright &copy; Django Central</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 
{% block content %}
<style>
    body {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
    }
    
    .head_text {
        color: black;
    }
    
    .card {
        box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
    }
</style>

<header class="masthead">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="site-heading">
                    <h3 class=" site-heading my-4 mt-3 text-black"> Welcome to my awesome Blog </h3>
                    <p class="text-light">We Love Django As much as you do..! &nbsp
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left">
            {% for post in post_list %}
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on}} </p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{post.content|slice:":200" }}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
    </div>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

post_details.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1>{% block title %} {{ object.title }} {% endblock title %}</h1>
        <p class=" text-muted">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on }}</p>
        <p class="card-text ">{{ object.content | safe }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

sidebar.html:

```
{% block sidebar %}

<style>
        .card{
            box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
        }
       img {
            width: 60%;
            height: auto;
            object-fit: contain;        
</style>

<!-- Sidebar Widgets Column -->
<div class="col-md-4 float-right ">
<div class="card my-4">
        <h5 class="card-header">O mnie</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        {% load static %}
        <center><img src="{% static 'blog/zdjecie.png' %}" alt="My image"></center>
        <p class="card-text"> This awesome blog is made on the top of our Favourite full stack Framework 'Django', follow up the tutorial to learn how we made it..!</p>
         <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="omnie/">Wiecej</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock sidebar %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in your index.html file. Since you're saving html tags in the database, you need to change

```
{{post.content|slice:":200" }}
```

to

```
{{post.content|safe|slice:":200" }}
```

Check this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/) to know more.

Also, there are many topics online about the security issues of saving html tags in the database. I recommend that you research about this and try to find an alternative approach.